# If the oh-my-god particle hit you, would you notice?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, collision, estimation

I was reading about the '[OMG particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle)' and was wondering what would happen if it hit a person (before it went through the atmosphere). I did a search and most answers said you wouldn't notice. Which seems odd since it had the same energy as a baseball going 60 miles per hour, and I would definitely notice that if it hit me.

I then thought maybe I should be looking at momentum instead of energy. I did some calculations and it appears that the proton's momentum would be only 10^-7 that of the baseball. So maybe that is the preferred measure of 'noticeable?'

Comment: When it "hits" you, some fraction of the energy will be "deposited" in your body tissue, and the rest will be carried away by a shower of particles that exit from the other side of your body. IDK what the fraction will be, but you won't be hurt by energy that you don't absorb.

Answer (score 0):

That something is felt by someone is a very bad definition for 'noticeable' in physics. We, as humans, will feel something only if it struck a nerve, or a sufficient portion of one. I would argue the OMG particle is so very small that it would be impossible for you to feel the strike. If there would be consequences or not is a different thing, such as, for example, alpha radiation can strike and cause damage to the DNA molecules, but you don't 'notice' the strike. You'll certainly notice the cancer a few months or years later though. That being said, until we can know for sure what the OMG particle is/was, the potential consequences of a strike on a human are uncertain.